# Word stop when navigating text with option-key

Tags: text, navigation

I use option and command to navigate text (which is awesome). I've read somewhere that you can specify the characters that constitute a word stop (underscores for example). However I can't find this anywhere.

Does anyone know where to set this?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose between a few settings in System Preferences, but I don't know any way to customize them.

[image]

The standard setting treats period and colon as part of (some) words.

ASCII special characters that are part of words:

- `'.:_` in Standard
- `'_` in English (United States, Computer)

ASCII special characters that are not part of the start or end of words:

- `` $+<=>^` `` in Standard
- `` $+<=>^` `` in English (United States, Computer)

`aa.11` and `aa'11` are never single words. `11.11` and `aa_11` are always single words.